# Easiest way to IP68 waterproof RJ45 cables/ports/splitting?

Tags: connector, cables, rj45, waterproof

Consider the following simple daisy-chain arrangement:

[image]

- Protocol is MODBUS. Electrical standard is RS485.
- Cables also carry 12v DC power (Power over Ethernet) to the sensors.
- All cables are CAT5e standard with Male-to-Male RJ45 connectors on both ends, so everything is connected via male-to-male CAT5e RJ45 cables.
- All 3-way splitter boxes are the following simply-connected Female-Female-Female RJ45 ports (no extra circuitry):

[image]

The system works fine, but it lacks moisture- and water-proofing. In order to make it suitable for outdoor operation, at least IP68 waterproofing standard must be implemented.

What is the easiest way to IP68 waterproof the 3-Way splitters while preserving the ease of plugging/unplugging RJ45 provides? I.e. without encasing the splitters in sealed boxes or hot-glue/silicon sealing.

Comment: Use outdoor rated RJ45 IP68 connectors on cable and splitter. Of course you can't use these cables and splitters then as you would also need outdoor rated cable. And since this is not Ethernet, sending 12V of course can't be called PoE, and even then it would be just non-standard, not PoE.

Comment: @Justme Thank you. I've scoured the online shops and Ebay, but there seems to be no IP68-rated 3-way splitters available off-the-shelf. But maybe I did not look in the right places. Do you know of any models?

Comment: " without encasing the splitters in sealed boxes.." X-Y problem?  Is this really a requirement?  Why can't the splitter (and other moisture sensitive bits) be protected in an enclosure(s) and use IP rated RJ45 bulkheads?

Answer (score 2):

Do what we do in the industry: use [M12 IEC circular connectors](https://www.idealvac.com/Pfeiffer-RS485-Communication-Cable-Connects-HiPace-Turbo-Pump-TC-Drive-Unit-to-OmniControl-Controller-M12-to-M12-Connectors/pp/P1012287). They make [M12 T-splitters](https://www.google.com/search?q=IEC+M12+connector++splitter&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZqtjlgub_AhVaIzQIHd6VDnYQ0pQJegQIMxAB&biw=2078&bih=1055&dpr=0.8). They are sealed.

[Pinout](https://manuals.sma.de/SBxx-1AV-41/en-US/2080835211.html)

Comment: That is a really good suggestion, and I was contemplating using these types of cables from the get go. However, I'd like to make sure that in case of a need for a longer cable, or a cable failure a non-technical person (i.e. on-site worker) could fix the problem themselves by simply going to the closest PC parts shop and getting a replacement CAT5/6

Comment: "and getting a replacement CAT5/6" Which won't be sealed. So you're back to square one: a cable that will fail in the field.